# Open a new Tab And write something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html code that I want to write to a blank page. I tried this approach but Chrome is blocking my pop-up attempt.

**How do I write my code to a new tab? and automatically change to that tab?**

```
 success: (function (code) {
           var codeHtml = '<div class="code">' + code.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />') + '</div>';
           var newWindow = window.open();
           newWindow.write(codeHtml);
       })
```

edit: I also need to give it a title

Comment: Tell chrome to allow popups?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `document` from `document.write()`:

```js
var codeHtml = '<div class="code">foo<br /></div>';
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.write(codeHtml);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4zeob2et/1/)

Note that you cannot switch to the tab, though. That's controlled by the browser at a level below that which JS has access to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is attempting to open a popup after an ajax request completes. This is, unfortunately, a good way to get your popup blocked by most popup blockers.

The best thing you can do is make sure that you open the new window synchronously from a user-interaction event. e.g. Browsers will (usually) let you open a popup if you do it directly in response to say a `click` event.

```
<script>
  function handleClick() {
    var newWin = window.open("https://google.com");
  }

  function handleClickDelayed() {
    // The `setTimeout` here "breaks" the connection between the click event and `window.open`, so most browsers will block the popup.
    setTimeout(handleClick, 1000);
  }
</script>

<button onclick="handleClick()">Click me</button>
<button onclick="handleClickDelayed()">Click me delayed (will likely be blocked)</button>
```

Ajax requests end up behaving like the `setTimeout` in the above example, they break the connection between the users click event and the `window.open` call and will be blocked as a result. A "trick" you can attempt is to open the window when a user clicks, and then update the opened page later once you have the result of your AJAX call.